# What is Kaisika Mahatmyam?

Tags: vaishnavism, identification-request

What is Kaisika Mahatmyam?

What does "Kaisika" mean?  Does it have something to do with the Vaishnavite devotee Nampaduvan who was afflicted by a Brahma Rakshasa?

Comment: Yes, it's about him.